# Results of tasks in async.auto

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am kind of confused with the logic of results which go from one task to the other task in [async.auto](https://github.com/caolan/async#auto). For example in the following code logic I added some data to models in `task1`, which is initially an output from `initialtask` and in `finalTask` added data to models from `task1` is reflected in `results.initialTask1` as well. Similarly added data in `task2` is reflected in `results.initialTask1` in `finalTask`.

**To sum up** all of `results.initialTask1`, `results.task1[0]`, `results.task2[0]`, `results.task3[0]` are identical in `finalTask`. Is this the logic of `async.auto`? Or is it something like reference by pointer in C++ which causes whatever changes for models in `task1`, it reflects in models in `initialTask` as well?

```
async.auto({
    initialTask: function(callback) {
        //Do some operations
        callback(null, name, initialModels);
    },
    task1: ['initialTask', function(callback, results) {
        var models = results.initialTask[1];
        //Add some more data to models
        callback(null, models);
    }],
    task2: ['initialTask', function(callback, results) {
        var models = results.initialTask[1];
        //Add some more data to models
        callback(null, models);
    }],
    task3: ['initialTask', function(callback, results) {
        var models = results.initialTask[1];
        //Add some more data to models
        callback(null, models);
    }],
    finalTask: ['task1', 'task2', 'task3', function(callback, results) {
        //Here the followings are the same: results.initialTask[1], results.task1[0], results.task2[0], results.task3[0]                               
    }]
});
```

I'm looking for any answer which helps me make sure that is the logic or not? I'm not necessarily looking for any official documents or ...

Comment: I'm looking for any answer which helps me make sure that is the logic or not? I'm not necessarily looking for any official documents or ...

Comment: will callback be the first argument or results, as per documentation, results  is the first parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Basically `async.auto` will execute all the functions in the order it deems necessary. So in your case `initialTask` will be called first. Then `task1`, `task2`, and `task3` will be called in parallel. Finally `finalTask` will be called with the results. The reason all the values are the same is related to JavaScript's [call-by-sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), meaning if you change a function parameter itself, then it won't affect the item that was fed into the parameter. If you change the internals of the parameter, it will carry up to the item.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language).

Example:

```
async.auto({
// this function will just be passed a callback
readData: async.apply(fs.readFile, 'data.txt', 'utf-8'),
showData: ['readData', function(results, cb) {
    // results.readData is the file's contents
    // ...
}]
}, callback);

async.auto({
get_data: function(callback) {
    console.log('in get_data');
    // async code to get some data
    callback(null, 'data', 'converted to array');
},
make_folder: function(callback) {
    console.log('in make_folder');
    // async code to create a directory to store a file in
    // this is run at the same time as getting the data
    callback(null, 'folder');
},
write_file: ['get_data', 'make_folder', function(results, callback) {
    console.log('in write_file', JSON.stringify(results));
    // once there is some data and the directory exists,
    // write the data to a file in the directory
    callback(null, 'filename');
}],
email_link: ['write_file', function(results, callback) {
    console.log('in email_link', JSON.stringify(results));
    // once the file is written let's email a link to it...
    // results.write_file contains the filename returned by write_file.
    callback(null, {'file':results.write_file, 
'email':'user@example.com'});
}]
}, function(err, results) {
console.log('err = ', err);
console.log('results = ', results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

async.auto  is very useful  and powerful function which is provided by Async  Lib .it have 3 fields
1-task
2- concurrency
3-callback

In Async.auto, Each function depends on its parent function except the first function, if any function will get any error during execution .then their child function or say .. their below-defined function will not get executed further, an error will occur with callback and the main callback will immediately return with an error

1- Task :- an Object 
 2- concurrency :- An optional integer for determining the maximum number of tasks that can be run in parallel. By default, as many as possible.
3- callback:- return the response

exapmle-

```
 AnyService.prototype.forgetPassword = function (res, email, isMobile, callback) {
    Logger.info("In AnyService service forgetPassword email...", email);
    db.User.findOne({
        email: email.toLowerCase(),
        deleted: false
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (!user) {
            configurationHolder.responseHandler(res, null, configurationHolder.LoginMessage.registerFirst, true, 403)
        } else {
            async.auto({
                token: function (next, results) {
                    return gereratePasswordToken(next, email, user, isMobile);
                },
                sendMail: ['token', function (next, result) {
                    return SendMailService.prototype.forgetPasswordMail(next, result.token, email, user.fullName);
                  }]
            }, function (err, result) {
                if (err == null && result != null) {
                    configurationHolder.ResponseUtil.responseHandler(res, null,      configurationHolder.LoginMessage.forgotPassword, false, 200)
                } else {
                    callback(new Error(configurationHolder.errorMessage.oops))
                }
            })
        }
    });
  }
```